# reading texts from a text file in C through fgets

Tags: c, file, fgets

my intent is to read the first 5 words of every line. but when I run this code everyword in the textfile prints out. Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

int main(void) {

```
char const* const fileName = "text.dat";

FILE* file = fopen(fileName, "r");

if (!file) {
    printf("\n Unable to open : %s ", fileName);
    return -1;
}

char line[50];

while (fgets(line, 5, file)) {
    printf("%s", line);
}
fclose(file);
return 0;
```

}

my intent is to read the first 5 words of every line. but when I run this code everyword in the textfile prints out. Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

Comment: Where's the code that counts five words?  That `5` you put in the `fgets` call limits it to five *characters*.  So it reads 5 characters, and prints them, then reads five more characters (probably from the same line) and prints them, etc., and so it prints the entire input.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to utilize the string function "strtok" to split up and count words.  Using your initial code, I added the following tweaks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char const* const fileName = "text.dat";

    FILE* file = fopen(fileName, "r");

    if (!file)
    {
        printf("\n Unable to open : %s ", fileName);
        return -1;
    }

    char line[129];
    const char delim[2] = " ";
    char * wd;

    while (fgets(line, 128, file))
    {
        wd = strtok(line, delim);
        int i = 0;
        while (i < 5 && wd != NULL)
        {
            printf("%s ", wd);
            wd = strtok(NULL, delim);
            i++;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    fclose(file);

    return 0;
}
```

Then a simple text file was set up with the following data.

```
Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
```

Following was the resulting output.

```
@Dev:~/C_Programs/Console/Parse/bin/Release$ ./Parse 
Now is the time for 
The quick brown fox jumps
```

For further information on using the "strtok" function, you might want to refer to this link [strtok usage](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strtok.htm).

Give that a try and see if it meets the spirit of your project.

Comment: I would suggest `fgets(line, 129, file)`, or even better, `fgets(line, sizeof(line), file)`.

Comment: Good point .  Makes it more universal.

Comment: thanks so much for the kind reply this helped me break thorugh the problems i was having !